# MySQL query using filesort and temporary

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I am using a simple MySQL query, but the performance is realy bad because of using ORDER BY. I can't figure out why MySQL is using filesort and temporary.

My query is:

```
EXPLAIN 
SELECT * FROM Events
INNER JOIN EventLogFiles ON ServerID = 42
AND Events.LogFileID = EventLogFiles.LogFileID
ORDER BY ReportID DESC , TimeWritten DESC 
LIMIT 100
```

This is the output of EXPLAIN:

[image: Mysql EXPLAIN output]

Table Events structure

[image: Table Events structure]

Table Events indexes

[image: Table Events indexes]

Table EventLogFiles structure

[image: Table EventLogFiles structure]

Table EventLogFiles indexes

[image: Table EventLogFiles indexes]

UPDATE:

I tried to create two new indexes, but both still force MySQL to use filesort and temporary.

```
ALTER TABLE Events ADD INDEX  `ReportID_TimeWritten_ServerID_LogFileID` ( ReportID DESC,  TimeWritten DESC,  ServerID,  LogFileID)

ALTER TABLE Events ADD INDEX  `ServerID_LogFileID_ReportID_TimeWritten` ( ServerID,  LogFileID, ReportID DESC,  TimeWritten DESC)
```

Comment: Can you output the first 100 records to a temporary table without ordering, and then order only those 100 records with another query?

Comment: Add Events.LogFileID to the multi-column index.

Comment: Could you try creating indexes `ServerID_ReportID_TimeWritten_LogFileID`, `ReportID_TimeWritten_ServerID_LogFileID` ? I think one of them will help.

Comment: It is still using temporary and filesort --> ALTER TABLE EVENTS ADD INDEX  `ServerID_ReportID_TimeWritten_LogFileID` ( ServerID, ReportID DESC , TimeWritten DESC , LogFileID )

Answer (score 4):

In order to utilize the index for both selection and sorting, you need to have all of the following columns in a multi-column index on Events: `(ServerID, LogFileID, ReportID, TimeWritten)`.

Currently, MySQL cannot utilize the existing multi-column index because it doesn't include `LogFileID`, which is in your `ON` clause.

If you ever have problems where MySQL is selecting from EventLogFiles first, you can change the `INNER JOIN` to a `STRAIGHT JOIN` to ensure that MySQL always elects from Events first, using your index.

Comment: Marcus, I followed your advice, but still the same problem, do you have any ideas?

Key: ServerID_LogFileID_ReportID_TimeWritten | key_len: 4 | Extra: Using temporary; Using filesort

Comment: Key_len cannot be 4 for the multi-column index. It should be 16. I would double check your query and index.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get that working without temp table and file sort, you must to create an index  `(ServerID, LogFileID, ReportID)` and `TimeWritten` must to be sequential like the `auto_increment` that you have been using in `ReportID`, so making the `ORDER BY ReportID(PK - Order Physical)` you must remove the filesort.